# Display different images on different devices

Tags: javascript, android, ios, css

I'm looking for a way to display different images on the same position, depending on the devices the website gets pulled up from.

More background: I placed my logo in the navbar - it fits perfectly on the desktop version to display it in one row - on the mobile version it is too long and gets extended to two rows. I want to use my full logo on the desktop site and only the small symbol in my logo on the mobile site.

Thanks.

Comment: So...CSS media queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that easily by using visible and hidden classes

**Use any of the following classes in order to hide a certain tag/element on a certain display and showing on the rest.**

1. hidden-xs
2. hidden-sm
3. hidden-md
4. hidden-lg

**Use any of the following classes in order to show a certain tag/element on a certain display and hiding on the rest.**

1. visible-xs
2. visible-sm
3. visible-md
4. visible-lg

Still need more explanation ? Hit me back :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Bootstrap, you can easily do it by adding classes to the images.
(http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities)